# E-mail notification for the creator

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to set up an e-mail notification for the person who add info on the Share point and also this e-mail needs to contain all info added into the share point itself by the same person. Is it possible?

Comment: Where is the information being added? A specific list or library or is this when anything is added to anywhere on the site?

Answer (score 2):

you can create an alert from the out of the box options also.

Go to AllItems.aspx page of particular list

[image]

on the top ribbon, you can create and customize your alert using settings.

Make sure that your SMTP service should be configurable for emails.

Answer (score 0):

yes,that is possible ,Create a workflow for that sharepoint list on item add.

Refer this tutorials site for create workflow
https://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-tutorials/Creating-workflow-sends-email/144025/161215-4.html#tab